# Angular.js don't bind the model in the html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am developing an app using Angular.js and html i want to bind a default date in a select combo box that i calculate in a .js file, but ng-model do not bind me the expected value.
This is the code for html:

```
<select ng-options="day as day for day in departureDateDays" ng-model="beginDateDay">
</select>
```

and this is how i calculate the value of beginDateDay:

```
var defaultDate = new Date();
defaultDate.setUTCDate(defaultDate.getUTCDate() + parseInt(data.departure.date.default,10));
$scope.beginDateDay = defaultDate.getUTCDate();
$scope.test = $scope.beginDateDay;
$scope.departureDateMonths = getMonthRange($scope.departureMinYear,$scope.departureMinMonth,$scope.departureMaxYear,$scope.departureMaxMonth);
$scope.departureDateMonth = defaultDate.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + (defaultDate.getUTCMonth() + 1);
```

I hope for a little help.

Comment: Check the value of defaultDate in console after 2nd line! What is the value?

Comment: its value is 21 the expected value because data.departure.date.default stores a int value: 3 as expected it adds this value to today number 18 and as result it is 21

Comment: @ncr07 Please elaborate the html code it is not as complete as required in js code.